# HTML5 AppCache - preview in browsers

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, html5-appcache

I'm implementing an appcache in my application and I have a lot of problems with setings it correctly.

For this specific moment I have problems to determine, if files loaded are for sure from the appcache and not from the regular cache?

Can someone provide me with links/tips how can I check that? E.g. in Chrome in the dev tools in Network tab there is placed a (from cache) text for cached resources, but how can I know this is the correct cache?

In Firefox sometimes on files which should be cached in appcache I have nitification in Firebug, that they are loaded from BFCache not AppCache and something like tjat houldn't happen.

So once again, can you provie me with e.g. some plugins for popular browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome) to check that?

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly declare a page to be cached by the AppCache by referencing a manifest file so you can be sure its using AppCache. A manifest file is

> simple text file that lists the resources the browser should cache for
>   offline access.

and,

> The manifest attribute should be included on every page of your web
>   application that you want cached.

```
<html manifest="example.appcache">
....
</html>
```

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

[BFCache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching) on the other hand is specific to Firefox (other browsers have similar implementation) and serves its purpose differently from AppCache.

AppCache helps your web apps be accessible offline while BFCache speeds up your backward and forward page navigation between visited pages.

You will no longer require any plugins aside from Firebug and the browser's built-in Developer tools if AppCache is implemented correctly

Comment: I know how to apply manifest file, I know the basics. I have situation like in this link: http://japhr.blogspot.com/2013/03/busting-appcache-with-iframes.html I have an iframe and all files are visible in appcache. The problem is with the iframe itself. If I remove the iframe and set the manifest on the page, then in IE11 the manifest is not even parsed, because the page has a no-store header. This is set to disable the back browser button after logout. That's why I used the iframe and right know I can't think of any solution for this.